# How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs

Tags: linux, path, cron

I'm trying to get cron to call in the correct PATHs. When I run a Python script from shell the script runs fine as it uses the PATHs set in bashrc but when I use cron all the PATHs are not used from bashrc. Is there a file I can enter the PATHs into for cron like bashrc or a way to call the PATHs from bashrc?

Sorry I don't think I worded this correctly, I can get the correct script to run (meaning the PATH to the script in crontab is not the problem here), it's just when that script is running I run a build and this uses the PATHs set in `.bashrc`. When I run the script when I'm logged in, the `.bashrc` PATHs are pulled in. Since cron doesn't run in a shell per say it does not pull in `.bashrc`. Is there a way of pulling this in without having to write a bash script wrapper?

Comment: also have a look at the suggestion given here for how to get bashrc settings to work for cronjobs: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15557777/1025391

Comment: The magic, simple and correct command to have your profile included in current environment is `source /etc/profile`, it should eat `.bashrc` and a whole lot of other potentially missing things for you. Explicit profile sourcing gets pretty useful if you want some scripts to run "standalone", it also protects from weird environments and so...

Comment: @exa +100  This makes `sh` scripts called by crontab work.  You can confirm it updates the path by adding a job like `* * * * * echo $PATH > ~/crontab_path.txt` and checking the file after a minute.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

I used `/etc/crontab`. I used `vi` and entered in the PATHs I needed into this file and ran it as root. The normal crontab overwrites PATHs that you have set up. [A good tutorial on how to do this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150626074155/http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5).

The systemwide cron file looks like this:

```
This has the username field, as used by /etc/crontab.
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file.
# This file also has a username field, that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user   command
42 6 * * *   root    run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
47 6 * * 7   root    run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
52 6 1 * *   root    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
01 01 * * 1-5 root python /path/to/file.py
```

Comment: This works with crontab -e at the user level and it is safer that way too.

Comment: Can I use bash instead of sh?

Comment: it is strange (to me) that the default PATH set in /etc/crontab as shown by @chrissygormley, and also set in my (Ubuntu) crontab, is different from the path in /etc/environment, specifically it puts /sbin and /bin ahead of /usr/sbin and /usr/bin. I have now changed this in my /etc/crontab to make it the same as the user environment.

Comment: Not working for me..I am outputting cron content to a file. Cron runs, file creates but it is not putting any content in it.

Comment: It seems that not all of the paths set in `/etc/crontab` are available to cron when running as root In Ubuntu 14.04. (`sudo crontab -e`)

Comment: @qed You can use `bash /path/to/scriptname` or `bash -c 'your bash commands here'` or simply put them in a script file with correct permissions and the correct [shebang.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) Perhaps see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) for an answer of mine with more details. You can also set `SHELL=/bin/bash` to run all your `cron` jobs with Bash, but this is probably overkill, and undesirable on any shared system where performance and security considerations etc trump convenience.

Answer (score 59):

Most likely, cron is running in a very sparse environment. Check the environment variables cron is using by appending a dummy job which dumps `env` to a file like this:

```
* * * * * env > env_dump.txt
```

Compare that with the output of `env` in a normal shell session.

You can prepend your own environment variables to the local crontab by defining them at the top of your crontab.

Here's a quick fix to prepend `$PATH` to the current crontab:

```
# echo PATH=$PATH > tmp.cron
# echo >> tmp.cron
# crontab -l >> tmp.cron
# crontab tmp.cron
```

The resulting crontab will look similar to chrissygormley's answer, with PATH defined before the crontab rules.

Answer (score 30):

You should put full paths in your `crontab`. That's the safest option.
If you don't want to do that you can put a wrapper script around your programs, and set the PATH in there.

e.g.

```
01 01 * * * command
```

becomes:

```
01 01 * * * /full/path/to/command
```

Also anything called from `cron` should be be very careful about the programs it runs, and probably set its own choice for the `PATH` variable.

EDIT:

If you don't know where the command is that you want execute `which <command>` from your shell and it'll tell you the path.

EDIT2:

So once your program is running, the first thing it should do is set `PATH` and any other required variable (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) to the values that are required for the script to run.
Basically instead of thinking how to modify the cron environment to make it more suitable for your program/script - make your script handle the environment it's given, by setting an appropriate one when it starts.

Comment: if its in your path use 'which command' and it will give you the full path

Comment: @Douglas Leeder -- When you say put the full path's into cron, do you mean put it into crontab or another file? If it is how would you go about that if the cron command is: '01 01 * * * command'. Thanks

Comment: @chrissygormley - Yes `crontab`.

Comment: Sorry there must be some confusion. I have reworded the question above.

Comment: You should prefer `type` and/or `command` over nonstandard utilities like `which` and `whereis`. Sometimes they exist and work, sometimes they don't.

Answer (score 30):

Adding a PATH definition into the user crontab with correct values will help...
I've filled mine with this line on top (after comments, and before cron jobs):

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

And it's enough to get all my scripts working... Include any custom path there if you need to.

Comment: For a user crontab this is should be the correct answer. Not everyone on a system can edit `/etc/crontab`.  This is the easiest answer on a user level. Good job @Treviño. Vote this up if you agree.

Comment: Perhaps compare with your interactive `PATH` and your system's default `PATH`, and adjust accordingly. For example, `/usr/local/sbin` is slightly unusual, but presumably correct on the OP's system. The ones with `sbin` in them tend to be administrative commands which typically are not on the default `PATH` for regular users, and so you might not need those.

Comment: Some third-party packages install their binaries somewhere like `/opt/acme` and so you'd add `/opt/acme/bin` or perhaps `/opt/acme/ajax/bin` to get those onto your `PATH`. Or, of course, for a quick and dirty one-off, just hard-code the location of the binary you want to run, like `/opt/acme/ajax/bin/anvil` instead of just `anvil`.

Answer (score 20):

Setting PATH right before the command line in my crontab worked for me:

```
* * * * * PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/path/to/some/thing
```

Comment: prefer this way.  or specify full path of script.

Comment: I don't think the path will keep growing, each time its run will be a new environment, with a fresh copy of PATH...

Comment: Can confirm that @jjcf89 is correct, PATH is fresh on each run.

Answer (score 16):

Make your variables work for you, this will allow access t

**Define your PATH in /etc/profile.d/*.sh**

[System-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Files with the .sh extension in the /etc/profile.d directory get executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in from the console or over ssh), as well as by the DisplayManager when the desktop session loads.

You can for instance create the file /etc/profile.d/myenvvars.sh and set variables like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

**Execute crontab with login option!**

[CRONTAB run script or command with Environment Variables](http://blog.geekslikeshinythings.com/2014/10/crontab-run-script-or-command-with.html)

```
0 9 * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/foo/crons/; bash -l -c 'php -f ./download.php'
0 9 * * * cd /var/www/vhosts/foo/crons/; bash -l -c download.sh
```

Comment: `/etc/profile.d` is a Debian invention. For systems which have this directory, this is vaguely reasonable, though not specific in any way to `cron` jobs; and so, you might want to avoid polluting the environment of unrelated jobs, and seek a different solution.

Answer (score 11):

### Problem

Your script works when you run it from the console but fails in cron.

### Cause

Your crontab doesn't have the right path variables (and possibly shell)

### Solution

Add your current shell and path the crontab

### Script to do it for you

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Date: August 22, 2013
# Author: Steve Stonebraker
# File: add_current_shell_and_path_to_crontab.sh
# Description: Add current user's shell and path to crontab
# Source: http://brakertech.com/add-current-path-to-crontab
# Github: hhttps://github.com/ssstonebraker/braker-scripts/blob/master/working-scripts/add_current_shell_and_path_to_crontab.sh

# function that is called when the script exits (cleans up our tmp.cron file)
function finish { [ -e "tmp.cron" ] && rm tmp.cron; }

#whenver the script exits call the function "finish"
trap finish EXIT

########################################
# pretty printing functions
function print_status { echo -e "\x1B[01;34m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function print_good { echo -e "\x1B[01;32m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function print_error { echo -e "\x1B[01;31m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function print_notification { echo -e "\x1B[01;33m[*]\x1B[0m $1"; }
function printline { 
  hr=-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  printf '%s\n' "${hr:0:${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}}"
}
####################################
# print message and exit program
function die { print_error "$1"; exit 1; }

####################################
# user must have at least one job in their crontab
function require_gt1_user_crontab_job {
        crontab -l &> /dev/null
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && die "Script requires you have at least one user crontab job!"
}


####################################
# Add current shell and path to user's crontab
function add_shell_path_to_crontab {
    #print info about what's being added
    print_notification "Current SHELL: ${SHELL}"
    print_notification "Current PATH: ${PATH}"

    #Add current shell and path to crontab
    print_status "Adding current SHELL and PATH to crontab \nold crontab:"

    printline; crontab -l; printline

    #keep old comments but start new crontab file
    crontab -l | grep "^#" > tmp.cron

    #Add our current shell and path to the new crontab file
    echo -e "SHELL=${SHELL}\nPATH=${PATH}\n" >> tmp.cron 

    #Add old crontab entries but ignore comments or any shell or path statements
    crontab -l | grep -v "^#" | grep -v "SHELL" | grep -v "PATH" >> tmp.cron

    #load up the new crontab we just created
    crontab tmp.cron

    #Display new crontab
    print_good "New crontab:"
    printline; crontab -l; printline
}

require_gt1_user_crontab_job
add_shell_path_to_crontab
```

### Source

https://github.com/ssstonebraker/braker-scripts/blob/master/working-scripts/add_current_shell_and_path_to_crontab.sh

### Sample Output

[image: add_curent_shell_and_path_to_crontab.sh example output]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest workaround I've found looks like this:

```
* * * * * root su -l -c command
```

This example invokes `su` as root user and starts the shell with the user's full environment, including $PATH, set as if they were logged in. It works the same on different distros, is more reliable than sourcing .bashrc (which hasn't worked for me) and avoids hardcoding specific paths which can be a problem if you're providing an example or setup tool and don't know what distro or file layout on the user's system.

You can also specify the username after `su` if you want a different user than root, but you should probably leave the `root` parameter before `su` command since this ensures `su` has sufficient privileges to switch to any user you specify.

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have more upvotes.  I tested and confirmed it works.  It's definitely the easiest way to pull in all of the paths for the user.  Are there downsides that users should be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

The default environment for cron jobs is very sparse and may be very different from the environment you develop your python scripts in. For a script that might be run in cron, any environment that you depend on should be set explicitly. In the cron file itself, include full paths to python executables and to your python scripts.

Answer (score 3):

On my AIX cron picks up it's environmental variables from /etc/environment ignoring what is set in the .profile.

Edit: I also checked out a couple of Linux boxes of various ages and these appear to have this file as well, so this is likely not AIX specific.

I checked this using joemaller's cron suggestion and checking the output before and after editing the PATH variable in /etc/environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have to make the same edits in various places, then roughly do this:

```
* * * * * . /home/username/.bashrc && yourcommand all of your args
```

The . space and then the path to .bashrc and the && command are the magic there to get your environment changes into the running bash shell. Too, if you really want the shell to be bash, it is a good idea to have a line in your crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: This is slightly dubious, in that `.bashrc` is primarily a configuration for interactive shell invocations, and so often contains stuff which is unrelated to and potentially unsuitable for a `cron` job. A more principled solution would be to break out settings you want everywhere into a separate file, and then `.` (source) that file from various other locations, i.e. your `cron` job and your `.profile` etc.

Answer (score 3):

@Trevino: your answer helped me solve my problem. However, for a beginner, trying to give a step by step approach.

1. Get your current installation of java via `$ echo $JAVA_HOME`
2. `$ crontab -e`
3. `* * * * * echo $PATH` - this lets you understand whats the PATH value being used by crontab at present. Run crontab and grab $PATH value used by crontab.
4. Now edit crontab again to set your desired java bin path: a) `crontab -e`; b) `PATH=<value of $JAVA_HOME>/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` (its a sample path); c) now your scheduled job/script like `*/10 * * * * sh runMyJob.sh &`; d) remove `echo $PATH` from crontab as its not needed now.

Answer (score 3):

Set the required PATH in your cron

```
crontab -e
```

Edit: Press `i`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:or_whatever

10 * * * * your_command
```

Save and exit `:wq`

Comment: The instruction to "press `i`" and the guidance for how to quit assumes that the reader is a `vi` victim. A better solution is probably to set `VISUAL` to the path of an editor you are familiar and comfortable with in your shell's configuration, like `export VISUAL=/usr/bin/emacsclient`

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already, but I thought that his would be useful to some. I had a similar issue that I recently solved ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17582975/python-script-not-working-in-cron-job-with-subprocess-call-to-pysaunter/17687950)) and here are the highlights of the steps I took to answer this question:

1. make sure that you have the variables you need in PYTHONPATH (found here and here and for more info here) inside the .profile or .bash_profile for any shell you want to test your script in to make sure it works.
2. edit your crontab to include the directories needed to run your script in a cron job (found here and here)

   a) be sure to include the root directory in the PATH variable (.) as explained here (basically if you are running an executable with your command it needs to be able to find root or the directory where the executable is stored) and probably these (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
3. in your crontab file, create a cronjob that will change directory to the directory where you have successfully ran the script before (i.e. Users/user/Documents/foo)

   a) This will look like the following:

   ```
   * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/foo; bar -l doSomething -v
   ```

Answer (score -4):

Should you use `webmin` then these are the steps how to set the `PATH` value:

```
System
  -> Scheduled Cron Jobs
       -> Create a new environment variable
            -> For user: <Select the user name>
            -> Variable name: PATH
            -> Value: /usr/bin:/bin:<your personal path>
            -> Add environment variable: Before all Cron jobs for user
```