# How to run a Ruby script using rbenv with cron

Tags: ruby, cron, rbenv

I'm trying to run a Ruby script using rbenv with cron.
I know that I need to load rbenv in order to have the right Ruby version loaded.

I've tried options like this:

> */10 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc; cd /data/app; ruby -v' >> /tmp/logfile.txt 2>&1

but as the session is not interactive, I'm not having the right Ruby version.
I've found example like this:

> 15 14 1 * * export BASH_ENV=/path/to/environment && /full/path/to/bash -c '/full/path/to/rvm_script.rb'

It didn't work neither. Then I wrote a loader, which only load rbenv in the current shell but it doesn't work.

> */1 * * * * /bin/bash -c '$HOME/.rbenv/loader.sh ; cd /data/app/; ruby -v ' >> /tmp/logfile.txt 2>&1

Now I'm searching for another way to load it ... any ideas?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've found a solution to load rbenv. Either with a loader importing rbenv to the PATH :

> */1 * * * * /bin/bash -c '. $HOME/.rbenv/loader.sh ; cd /data/app/; ruby -v'

The '.' before '$HOME/.rbenv/loader.sh' is important, it runs the script in the current shell

Or without loader, which is better :

> */1 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /data/app/; ruby -v'

Comment: Note that your loader only needs to contain the `$PATH` changes: `export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH`. And you don't even have to cd, just run `ruby /data/app/script_name.rb` and rbenv will find the correct version. You can omit the shims path if you don't need it, as you already know.

Comment: `* * * * * * /bin/bash -c '. /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh; ruby -v'` for system wide rbenv installations and users without shell / home dir

Comment: You can set PATH in your whole crontab not just for a specific entry.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/629057

Answer (score 20):

A better solution is to simply use the command `bash -lc` command. This will read your bash profile file, which would setup rbenv. From the `bash` man page:

> -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell
>
> When  bash  is  invoked  as  an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it
>          first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading  that  file,  it
>          looks  for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the
>          first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is  started  to  inhibit
>          this behavior.

Comment: I don't recommend this, because it can potentially add a lot of overhead if `.bash_profile`, etc does stuff that only an interactive shell needs. You might even cause trouble if you've aliased certain bash commands.

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/15-cron-rbenv-bundle-exec-rake-task   `* * * * * PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin && bash -lc "cd /home/deploy/apps/myapp && RACK_ENV=production bundle exec rake event:process
`

Comment: @EstebanFeldman Make sure that 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' is in your .bashrc and that .bashrc is loaded from .bash_profile.

Comment: This makes the silent assumption, that the cron job user actually has a home dir.

Answer (score 5):

Even though kmmndr's answer is correct, I also like the `bash -l`-approach.

Opening a non-interactive login shell keeps things simpler and since my Rails applications and Ruby scripts all run under the same user, overhead is not a problem.

So instead of

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /data/app/; ruby -v'
```

I do

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -lc 'cd /data/app/; ruby -v'
```

As noted in the above answer, `bash -l` will act as if you login normally, which means that your rbenv environment will already be set up (as long as you have the appropriate lines in your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` of `/etc/profile.d/*`).

If you need more detail, I wrote [a blog post](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/running-ruby-scripts-from-within-a-cron-job-in-an-rbenv-environment) about this topic.

Answer (score 4):

This answer from @Kelvin worked for me:

```
*/1 * * * * PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH ruby -v >> ~/test.out
```

Comment: Seems the cleanest to me.

Answer (score 2):

For my backup script in Ruby I simply use `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec ruby [options] /path/to/ruby/script.rb`. Try this:

```
* * * * * ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec ruby -v > ~/rbenv-ruby-version.txt
```

Comment: And you ran it once a minute, every single minute of every day. You probably wanted `0 * * * *`, so that it runs once an hour.

Comment: This was set up so that I could test if the correct Ruby was running as soon as possible. Once confirmed I removed that line. It's not really a job I want to keep running in the server. The actual back-up command is another one.