# crontask generate by Whenever doesn't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rbenv, whenever

I have this cronfile :

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: mtaville_staging

* * * * * cd /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20141202140931 && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake cinemas:import --silent

# End Whenever generated tasks for: mtaville_staging
```

but it doesn't run the task.

When I had this :

```
* * * * * cd /home/mtaville/ && touch "echo.txt"
```

The file "echot.txt" is created... But not my task !

*EDIT*

```
nohup: les entrées sont ignorées
nohup: impossible d'exécuter la commande «cinemas:import»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

*EDIT FINAL*

Here is my crontask :

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/current ; RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake cinemas:import > /tmp/log.txt 2>&1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try run the task not silently but with output-forwarding to a file:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec nohup cinemas:import >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1
```

so for [cron](/questions/tagged/cron) the [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) has [special wrappers](http://rvm.io/deployment/cron), which should be run to setup proper environment, like follows:

```
* * * * * cd folder; RAILS_ENV=staging /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1@projectX/bundle exec nohup cinemas:import >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1
```

if you are using the [rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv), the [script runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434922/ruby-script-using-rbenv-in-cron) will be seen as follows:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -c '. $HOME/.rbenv/loader.sh; cd folder ; RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec cinemas:import >/tmp/log.txt 2>&1'
```

Comment: @p0k3 then add the output here

Comment: @p0k3 do you use the rvm/rbenv ?

Comment: Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: Yes I use it - the file said Could Not locate Gemfile

Comment: @p0k3 so the folder `/home/mtaville/mtaville_staging/releases/20141202140931` has no **Gemfile**?

Comment: When I tun it in the right folder (good release) I have this : 
nohup: les entrées sont ignorées
nohup: impossible d'exécuter la commande «cinemas:import»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

Comment: the is a gemfile in that folder

Comment: @p0k3 I've updated the post. and try it without `nohup`

Comment: I use rbenv, no rvm :/