# Whenever gem in rails is not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, cron, whenever

I have a cron job for emailing the users in the system and it doesn't want to run. I'm getting the following error message in the log:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'cron:deliver_email'
/Users/ghost/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@maalify/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/ghost/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@maalify/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

my schedule.rb is looking like that

```
set :environment, "development"
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}


every 1.minute do
  command "gem install rake"
  rake 'cron:deliver_email'
end
```

The stated rake task (`rake 'cron:deliver_email'`) is running correctly if I'm it from the command line with rake cron:deliver_email

I've added whenever to my Gemfile with the not require statement (:require => false).

thats how my cron job is looking like

```
▶ whenever 
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'gem install rake >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/ghost/code/IdeaProjects/maalify && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake cron:deliver_email --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell cron to load rvm environment.  See details here:

https://rvm.io/deployment/cron

Comment: And how about rbenv in production. because im using rbenv in production.

Comment: The error output you posted suggests that `rvm` is being used.  You should try not to use different tools between your environments.  Anyhow, for `rbenv` see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434922/ruby-script-using-rbenv-in-cron