# How to run cronjob for ruby script that runs from bash terminal

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, cron

I normally run [stinkypete.rb script](https://gist.github.com/inertia186/db94986d168f7b35034b0d7ccba6f2b4) using bash terminal and then run

```
  ruby stinkypete.rb
```

I'm trying to create cronjob for same using nano editor in ubuntu 16.04 and here is line for crontab that i've written.

```
*/1 * * * * export /home/orion/.bashrc -c '/home/orion/stinkypete/stinkypete.rb'
```

Checking service cron status, its running but script doesn't work.
Is there any other path that I need to load in crontab?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: You may  wanna check this gem [cron jobs in Ruby](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Comment: by doesn't work i mean script doesn't run , I checked whenever gem but it requires config file which my script doesn't have

Comment: If you are using rvm or  some other ruby manager，this is because cron know nothing about where is your ruby and gems, you may want to load some ruby environment, like load ruby to the  $PATH`, check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

Comment: I'm using rbenv

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434922/ruby-script-using-rbenv-in-cron

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using rbenv, cron job will not kown where is you ruby before your tell him, so you need init rbenv first, so try this

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash -c 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" ; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; ruby /home/orion/stinkypete/stinkypete.rb'
```