# Cant get Cron to work on this Ruby Script

Tags: ruby, cron

Im trying to run this cron

```
49 15 * * * ruby  /Users/nikosalt/Desktop/playing/twilio_send_text.rb
```

on my ruby script twilio_send_text.rb which looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = 'AC5179a0c973e8a059da8676877887f65'
auth_token = 'my twilio auth token'
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token


from = '+15146137221' # Your Twilio number
to = '+15142383468' # Your mobile phone number

client.messages.create(
from: from,
to: to,
body: "hello from cron"
)
```

When I run the cron. I keep getting this error:

```
Subject: Cron <niko@nikolass-MacBook-Pro> ruby  
/Users/nicolassaltarelli/Desktop/playing/twilio_send_text.rb
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=nicolassaltarelli>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=nicolassaltarelli>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/nicolassaltarelli>
Date: Thu,  8 Mar 2018 16:05:00 -0500 (EST)
```

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- twilio-ruby (LoadError)
>
> from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>
> from /Users/nicolassaltarelli/Desktop/playing/twilio_send_text.rb:2:in `'

I would love some help on working around this.

Comment: Are you using rvm or rbenv?

Comment: @JacktheRandom Im using rbenv

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `rbenv`, you need to create a wrapper for cron, for example as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434922/ruby-script-using-rbenv-in-cron).

Most likely what's happening is you've got 2 ruby interpreters on your computer: the one that's managed by `rbenv`, which you use for development and to run the script on the console; and then you've got your system ruby, which is most likely invoked by cron. Those two rubies most likely have different versions and have different sets of gems installed.

Alternatively, you could switch to your system ruby and install `twilio-ruby`.

Answer (score 1):

Install twilio-ruby gem.

```
gem install twilio-ruby
```

This will resolve your issue.

Cron task will be:

```
49 15 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /Users/nikosalt/Desktop/playing/twilio_send_text.rb'
```

Comment: I put this in my cron?

Comment: No, run this in cmd/terminal.

Comment: I did do this and am still running into the same problem. I think @jack the random is right and I have to put in a wrapper

Comment: I think @jack the Random is right. You can replace above cron with 
**49 15 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby /Users/nikosalt/Desktop/playing/twilio_send_text.rb'**

Comment: this worked! thank you. My reputation is still not high enough to upvote your answer. but thank you!