# How to run Ruby script (Rbenv) on bash scipt (Crontab)

Tags: ruby, bash, cron

How can I run a ruby script (rbenv) in bash script for crontab?

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
process=ruby
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process > /dev/null
then
    exit
else
    ruby /home/jason/ruby/project.rb &
fi

exit
enter code here
```

It works if I run the script as:

```
./{nameofscript}.sh
```

but it does not work when I put it on crontab. My crontab setting is like this:

```
*/2 * * * * root sh /home/jason/ruby/run.sh
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby script using rbenv in cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434922/ruby-script-using-rbenv-in-cron)

Comment: where is the name of the file of my ruby script?

Comment: @JASONALBERTSOEGIHARTO 
Think anothermh mean that already exist similar answered question.

Answer next:
*/2 * * * * root /home/jason/ruby/run.sh
and check is your script has enough rights for execution:
chmod +x you_script_name

Answer (score 1):

`rbenv` is not loaded under cron execution session.

You can try to add them dynamically on your `$PATH` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH
process=ruby
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $process > /dev/null
then
    exit
else
    ruby /home/jason/ruby/project.rb &
fi
exit
```

Comment: can you explain me about this code?PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATHp

Answer (score 0):

1/ you should need to specify sh in your crontab (replace sh /home/jason/ruby/run.sh by /home/jason/ruby/run.sh)

2/ in any case, you may consider using **nohup** instruction in front of the following instruction, to ensure it won't be hang up during execution

```
nohup ruby /home/jason/ruby/project.rb &
```