# Cron job does NOT get the environment variables set in .bashrc

Tags: bash, cron, environment-variables

Here is my cron job:

```
plee@dragon:~$ crontab -l
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'source ~/.bashrc; echo $EDITOR > /tmp/cronjob.test'
```

and inside `~/.bashrc` file, I have `export EDITOR=vim`, but in the final `/tmp/cronjob.test` file, it's still empty?

So how can I get the environment variables (set in `.bashrc` file) and use it in my cron job?

```
plee@dragon:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
plee@dragon:~$ uname -a
Linux dragon 3.2.0-26-generic-pae #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 16:45:14 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

If use this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c -x 'source ~/.bashrc; echo $EDITOR > /tmp/cronjob.test' 2> /tmp/cron.debug.res
```

In `/tmp/cron.debug.res`:

```
...
++ return 0
+ source /home/plee/.bashrc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return
+ echo
```

BTW, the `.bashrc` file is the default one came with Ubuntu 12.04, with the exception that I added one line `export EDITOR=vim`.

If I don't use the cron job, instead, just directly do this on the command line:

```
source .bashrc; echo $EDITOR # Output: vim
```

Comment: what happens if you `cat ~/.bashrc` into a temp file?

Comment: what do you mean by `cat ~/.bashrc`? It has a line: `export EDITOR=vim`.  I'm asking why the `echo` command does NOT pick up the `$EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, in the cron entry, instead of `source`ing the file, use `cat` to confirm that it can be read by `cron`.

Comment: Yes, it can read `* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cat ~/.bashrc > /tmp/cronjob.test'`

Comment: I just tried a similar cron command and it worked fine, interpreting ~ correctly and echo'ing the shell variable from ~/.bashrc. Could that suggest there is an error in ~/.bashrc ??

Comment: can you change the crontab entry to: `* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c -x 'source ~/.bashrc; echo $EDITOR > /tmp/cronjob.test' 2> /tmp/cron.debug.res` and post the contents of `/tmp/cron.debug.res`

Comment: @Alex, the `/tmp/cron.debug.res` exists, but empty.

Comment: I've edited my question, it was meant to redirect stderr instead of stdin.

Comment: looks like in your `source ~/.bashrc` `return`s without doing anything if some variable is empty (`[ -z "$something" ]`). I'm not running Ubuntu, can you also post the .bashrc file?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The reason for `source ~/.bashrc` not working is the contents on your `~/.bashrc` (default one from Ubuntu 12.04). If you look in it you will see on lines 5 and 6 the following:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

`PS1` variable is set for an interactive shell, so it's absent when run via `cron`, even though you are executing it as a login shell. This is confirmed by contents of the file produced by `/bin/bash -l -c -x 'source ~/.bashrc; echo $EDITOR > /tmp/cronjob.test'`:

```
+ source /home/plee/.bashrc
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ return
```

To make `source ~/.bashrc` work, comment out the line that checks for presence of the `PS1` variable in `~/.bashrc`:

```
#[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

This will make `bash` execute the entire contents of `~/.bashrc` via `cron`

Comment: Or set `$PS1` to some arbitrary value before `source`ing the `.bashrc` file; that way you don't have to change `.bashrc`.

Comment: That worked for me -- I have no idea why it was set that way, but it seems to have done the trick after hours of trying other stuff!

Comment: this does not work for me on debian for some reason. I still don't get my `~/.bashrc` in cronjobs.

Comment: There is a reason this code exists in the file. The proper solution is to move code which should be executed by noninteractive shells to a different configuration file. A common arrangement is to put things you need in `cron` jobs etc in a separate file, and `.` (aka source; but the `source` command is only available in Bash, and cannot be used in `sh`) that file from your `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile` and/or `.zshrc` and/or `cron` jobs as required.

Answer (score 13):

Answer provided by @alex is correct but in Ubuntu 13.10 the code has been modified a little.  There is no $PS1 variable but in lines 6-9 there is a code

```
case $- in 
   *i*) ;;       
   *) return;; 
esac
```

Just commenting out the line which returns works. i.e. the code below works

```
case $- in 
   *i*) ;;       
#   *) return;; 
esac
```

Comment: Take out the entire `case` statement if you don't want this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried a file `.env_setup_rc` file with only one line `export EDITOR=vim`, surprisingly it's working.

So I guess there is something in `.bashrc` conflicting with the cron job bash command.