# Scrapy Warning Disabled HttpCacheMiddleware

Tags: python, cron, scrapy

I get this warning when running scrapy :

```
 [scrapy] WARNING: Disabled HttpCacheMiddleware: Unable to find scrapy.cfg file to infer project data dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `scrapy.cfg` file?  Are you running from the command line?  If so, you should be running from the same directory as `scrapy.cfg`.

What does your project directory look like.  It shoud look something like:

```
.
├── dirbot
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── dmoz.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── README.rst
└── scrapy.cfg
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using `cron`, try not to (meaning don't) use the `root` user.  You can add the PATH info right into the crontab: [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths#answer-2409369)

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:...:/absolute/path/to/my/scrapy/project
```

Comment: Project directory is the same as the one you described, the spider is called from a scheduler.php file in the same dir as scrapy.cfg

Comment: How are you calling scrapy?  Popen()?  who is calling scheduler.php? Apache? It sounds like the user does not have this directory in their Python path.

Comment: a cron job calls scheduler.php which runs the spiders that should be running now.

Comment: What is the cron user?  He does not have your directory in his Python path.

Comment: The cron user is root, how do I add the directory to his python path?