# Crontab not working or shell script´s wrong?

Tags: shell, centos, cron, vpn

I tried to setup a cronjob with crontab to run a shell script every 10 minute. But it´s not working. I want the shellscript to delete the specific file "/var/log/messages" every 10 min.

The Shell Script file:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Remove Files 
rm -f /var/log/messages
```

The Crontab -E Config file:

```
*/10 * * * * /vpndel/script
```

But when i check the log file the text is still there after 10 minutes have gone?
What could be wrong?

Comment: just put this in the `root` crontab: `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/rm -f /var/log/messages/*` (this will delete all logs in the directory messages, if you want to delete a specific file just name it there, if messages is a file its just `/var/log/messages`)

Comment: @Alex: You're assuming `/var/log/messages` is a directory. On at least two systems I've just checked, its a file.

Comment: @Keith then its `*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/rm -f /var/log/messages`

Comment: @Alex: Yes, invoking `rm` (just `rm` should be fine, no need to specify `/usr/bin/rm`) should work -- but the OP might want to be able to modify `/vpndel/script` later on without changing the crontab. Incidentally, `rm` is typically `/bin/rm`, not `/usr/bin/rm`; `/usr/bin/rm` probably won't exist unless `/usr/bin` is a symlnk to `/bin`.

Comment: @Keith in a crontab you always have to use the full path to the program :) I'm runing `Arch Linux` and it's in `/usr/bin` on my system, but to find out where `rm` is you can always do a `whereis rm` on your system.

Comment: @Alex: No you don't, at least not on any system I've ever used. The default `$PATH` for cron jobs is typically `/usr/bin:/bin`. Try adding a cron job `* * * * * env > cron-env` and see what appears in `cron-env`.

Comment: @Keith Don't know which systems you use but in order to do that you have to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths) on most systems.

Comment: @Alex Thanks , How do i add so everytime its done its sends a mail to a specific address? In order to being enable to check that the task was crontab was acually executed?

Comment: @user2985180 Put `MAILTO=email@address.com` on top of your crontab. And make sure `postfix` or your mail program is properly configured.

Comment: @Alex: Not on Debian, Ubuntu, or Linux Mint. cron jobs are given a very sparse environment, but with a valid `$PATH`. `man 5 crontab` if you're using Vixie cron; on my system it specifically says that `$PATH` is set to `"/usr/bin:/bin"`. Please try the `env > cron-env` that I suggested; I'd be interested in seeing the results.

Comment: I get a error in the mail i recived saying "/bin/sh: /usr/bin/rm: No such file or directory" And i was using Alex´s Cronjob code this time. "*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/rm -f /var/log/messages"

Comment: @user2985180: Replace `/usr/bin/rm` by `rm`

Comment: Still doesnt work , not it even wont send me a mail regarding the cron job :/

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to check:

1. Is your `/vpndel/script` file executable?
2. Are you executing it from an account that has write permission on `/var/log` (that's probably just `root`)? Specifically, are you running the `crontab` command as root?
3. Are you sure it's not deleting the file? Could the system just be recreating it?

(I won't ask *why* you want to delete `/var/log/messages`, but it seems like an odd thing to do.)