# Why is curl not producing output when run in a shell script from cron?

Tags: shell, curl, cron

I have a shell script for getting data from some servers, in `~/.bin/shellScript` :

```
OLD="$(curl --silent http://someServer:12345/stats.json | json someKey)"
NEW="$(curl --silent http://otherServer:12345/stats.json | json someKey")

echo "OLD $OLD - NEW $NEW"
```

I want to echo the results for running it interactively, but I've been wanting to log the results collected too.
So `crontab -e`, and add `*/5 * * * * /home/user/.bin/shellScript >> /media/dump/scriptDump`.

Running the script interactively works fine - I get `OLD 123 - NEW 456`, but when I look at what's been running from cron, I get `OLD - NEW` with no data being grabbed with curl.

Comment: What if you add the full path of `json` on `json someKey`? Crontab doe s work in a limited environment and some paths can be missing, so you need to give it the full of it.

Comment: It never occurred to me that I needed to fix $PATH in the shellscript (even though I knew that cron had a limited env'). /facepalm

Comment: Hehe it always happens to all of us, no problem. So does it mean that now it is working to you?

Comment: Yeah. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered in the comments, you need to add the full path of `json` when you are calling it. This is because crontab's limited environment.

So instead of

```
OLD="$(curl --silent http://someServer:12345/stats.json | json someKey)"
NEW="$(curl --silent http://otherServer:12345/stats.json | json someKey")
```

it has to be

```
OLD="$(curl --silent http://someServer:12345/stats.json  | /path/to/json someKey)"
NEW="$(curl --silent http://otherServer:12345/stats.json | /path/to/json someKey)"
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[[Note your second line had `")` instead of `)"`]]

---

Otherwise, you can also add the `json` path into crontab, as indicated on [How to get CRON to call in the correct paths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388087/1983854):

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin: ... :/path/of/json
```