# AWS not working working from Cronjob

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, cron

So I have a script to download a file from AWS daily and append it to a spread sheet. To do this I have set up a cronjob.

The Script works fine when I run it manually, but does not work when running from the cronjob.

The code has a line:

```
aws s3 cp s3://My/files/backup/ ~/home/AnPoc/ --recursive --exclude "*.tgz" --include "*results.tgz"
```

And in the email I recieve from the cronjob execution, I see the following error message:

```
./AnPoc/DayProcessing.sh: line 14: aws: command not found
```

I don't know why the command is not being found. Any help would be great.

Comment: This darn $hi7 should be documented by AWS in a section on creating cron for s3 cli.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

First: check where on your system the executable `aws` is stored. Use this command:

```
$ which aws
/usr/bin/aws # example output, can differ in your system
```

Now, place a variable called `$PATH` in your crontab before the script:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Those paths separated by `:` define where should be search for the exectable. In the example above it's `/usr/bin`. You have to check all executables in your cron job that they are available.

**Another thing:** try to avoid path with a tilde (`~`) in cronjobs. Use `/home/user` instead.

Comment: If you `echo $PATH` you'll see that your session has the variable loaded. However when you execute from crontab it doesn't.

Comment: Saved my ar$e... had to create and move backups of my mail server to s3 bucket. when I ran my script (with aws s3 cp ...) manually it worked, just adding the `PATH` was needed to make it work with cron. I swear if it were'nt for your post, I'd never be able to figure that out myself in another year.

Comment: @Ev. thanks for your comment, I noticed it even before the answer. It made me do a simple test by redirecting output of path to a file and the rest was explained in the answer above.

Comment: If you don't know, where to put in the crontab, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/1386952

Comment: despite  following all the requirements, still I am not able execute the cronjob when clubbing it with s3 command, can anyone please advice what am I doing wrong.  `/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp /home/ubuntu/sqlbackup.sql 's3://bucketName/db/sqlbackup.sql`

Answer (score 36):

You should use the full path for the `aws` command. For example, `/usr/local/bin/aws`

Comment: @ user5735796 - when script is run through cron, it searches for aws executable in predefined locations as configured in $PATH variable. If aws is not installed in these locations, the command can't be found. So, either use the complete path to executable or add your aws location to $PATH variable.

Answer (score 10):

Put this code before your command line to be executed into crontab -e

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is very helpful for me to resolve a similar issue had with EKS commands such as `kubectl get po`

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was to specify the path explicitly in the script:

```
ROOTDIR=/home/myusername
LOGDIR=$ROOTDIR/logs
DUMPDIR=$ROOTDIR/db_backup
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/db_backup.log

$ROOTDIR/.local/bin/aws s3 cp $DUMPDIR/myappname-`date +"%Y-%m-%d"` s3://my-bucket-name/backups/myappname-`date +"%Y-%m-%d"` --recursive >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

As a previous poster said, use `which aws` to find the location of aws.

Answer (score 0):

If you have aws in your profile, you could also include your profile by adding `. $HOME/.profile`

`* * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command`

Answer (score 0):

If you install aws console using snap then the absolute/executable address will be like /snap/bin/aws otherwise its looks like /usr/bin/aws . It can be different according to your installation.
You can find this path using `$ whereis aws` .

eg :

```
snap/bin/aws s3 sync --exclude "/path to exclude" /pathtosync s3://bucketname/
```