# AWS S3 Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am making a Cron Job in AWS Server and I have this File Handling function which creates JSON file. I already have Amazon S3 Cloud Storage, and I want my JSON file saved inside it. How can I do it? I tried to locate the directory for Amazon S3 Storage using Filezilla but found nothing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you have to put another command into your cron.

After you create a Json file, you have to use awscli to upload your json to S3 storage.

Here is how to install it.

[installation guide](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_TH&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=english_command_line_b&sc_content=aws_cli_bmm&sc_detail=%2Bcli%20%2Baws&sc_category=command_line&sc_segment=211464967893&sc_matchtype=b&sc_Country=TH&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!211464967893!b!!g!!%2Bcli%20%2Baws&ef_id=WrCQXAAAAKQ0liua:20180717035447:s)

after its set up, you can use aws s3 command to upload it.

have a look here for more information.

[S3 upload command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

I guess this this a command you need to add.

`aws s3 cp ./yourfile.json s3://your-bucket-name/`

Comment: naah.. it didn't sorry. I want it to run together with cron, so my project will save the JSON file to my s3 bucket automatically.
I also tried shell_exec() inside the cron function but it seems like the 'aws s3' command not found.

Comment: have you install `aws-cli`

Comment: yes @Natsathorn, i can run aws command using terminal but when i try to do it in shell_exec() or exec() it returns error

Comment: it says aws not found

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480860/aws-not-working-working-from-cronjob

Comment: Will mark your answer green if it will work, i have other things to get done and i will come back to this. :) thank you!