# cron job not working from PHP script

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php file `push.php` to send push notification. I can run this php file from browser `http://myserver.com/push.php` and it sends push notification properly. I want to run this `push.php` automatically after 10 minutes.

My server is `Linux shared server` from `bluehost.com`. php version `5.4.39`. So I choose cron job feature in cpanel. I have insert my mail so when `push.php` run / cron works and I receive mail.

I followed `https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/168` and set time 10 minute and command `php -q /home2/applusme/public_html/pushfolder/push.php` where `/home2/applusme` is showing beside home icon and `pushfolder` is folder. I received mail but push is not sending.

I tried many ways but push not sent. below is push command and what i get in mail body from `Cron Daemon <root@box809.bluehost.com>`

1. `php -q /home2/applusme/public_html/pushfolder/push.php`

mail content: `<script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.reload();</script>`

2. `wget http://myserver.com/push.php`

mail content:

```
`http://myserver.com/push.php
Resolving myserver.com... 62.59.23.60
Connecting to myserver.com|62.59.23.60|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: “push.php”`
```

3. `/usr/local/php5/bin/php5 /home2/applusme/public_html/pushfolder/push.php`

mail content: `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /usr/local/php5/bin/php5: No such file or directory`

4. `cd /home2/applusme/public_html/pushfolder; /usr/local/php5/bin/php5 -q push.php`

mail content: `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /usr/local/php5/bin/php5: No such file or directory`

5. `curl http://myserver.com/push.php`
   mail content:

   ```
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                            Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
   100    72    0    72    0     0    132      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   133
   ```
6. `php /home2/applusme/public_html/pushfolder/push.php`
   mail:

   ```
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=ds4glu5kcbtu0tg95orkn2uci7; path=/
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-type: text/html

   <script type="text/javascript">window.top.location.reload();</script>
   ```

I have spend more than 5 hours in this issue but no luck. Please suggest me what can I do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure push is working fine? I mean `push.php` is able to do his all functionality?

Comment: `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: /usr/local/php5/bin/php5: No such file or directory` Did you set the right PHP path for the `cron` user ?

Comment: yes, push is working fine. all required settings for sending push notification are implemented into `push.php` and I am getting push notification into my android phone and iPhone both

Comment: Note that sessions and javascript will not work when you use cron as there is no browser involved.

Comment: @AkramFares, I don't know how to set right PHP path for the cron user.Will you please help me

Comment: Are you going to set cron.php in your `cpanel ` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths Check here.

Comment: @jeroen, You are 100% correct and my cron is running fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem from @jeroen help. I have included `include_once('includes/dbconfig.php');` into my `push.php`. There was `javascript` code into `dbconfib.php`. I removed javascript code and it works fine.

Thank you all