# Running jar with cron throws error: '/bin/sh: 1: java: not found'

Tags: java, linux, cron

I have scheduled my job to run every day at 12:30 with this command:

```
30 12 * * * java -jar test.jar
```

It throws error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: java: not found
```

I tried to run this command: `java -jar test.jar` from shell and it worked just fine.

Now I don't understand. I would say it is happening because `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not set, but then why it works from shell?

Comment: Your cron job does not run as the same user as you work in shell, right?

Comment: How may I find out? I use shell as root, cron might be running as tomcat or bitnami I guess, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that the shell could not locate the `java` binary to execute. This has nothing to do with the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but with the `PATH` variable which is consulted by `sh` to find any command.

When you run your task from `cron`, the shell did not receive the same initialization as your interactive shell where the command works for you. You'll equally find that `JAVA_HOME` isn't set there, either.

Comment: Sounds as a true, what is the resolution then? To add java/bin to the path variable?

Comment: You should study in general how `cron` is properly used. For example check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths).

Answer (score 1):

Your login shell environment is different from the one your cronjob has. Use `env`to print your environment.

Check the path on both - 
Within cron (something like)
`30 08 * * * env > ~/cronenv`.
In your login shell just use `env`. Then compare the PATH variables.
As @Marko Topolnik already stated your PATH within cron obviously does not contain your java executables.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line into your crontab file that contains the path that you need:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
PATH=.....
```

You probably need something like this:

`PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

You can also use `echo $PATH` to find out what you have in your regular environment and simply use that value.

Answer (score 0):

Another option i tried is to use the path of the java installed.

1. Make sure java is installed with below command

> java -version

2. Check the path of java installed

> whereis java

3. provide the full path to run the app

> 30 12 * * * /path_from_prev_step/java -jar test.jar

This will also allow you to run this jar with different java portable version if the server has a older version installed.