# Cannot run a python script using crontab

Tags: python, linux

I am struggling to run the a python script as a cron job.

I am logged in as root
the permission for the python script is

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2374 Mar  1 22:49 k_collab_spark.2.py
```

I am starting the script with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I tested the pythong script
if i do "./k_collab_spark.2.py` this work fine.

on the crontab i have set the job as

```
15 12 * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/testme/SPARK/k_collab_spark.2.py >> /var/log/kspark.log
```

I do not see any message on the log file

Once i adde 2>&1 it gives an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/kabeer/SPARK/k_collab_spark.2.py", line 2, in 
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests but if i execute the service manually it is successful . WHen i run it manually it works fine

Tried defining the path but still the same issue

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests

Any idea what i am missing.. Appreciate any help around this.

Comment: [pythong](http://www.amazon.com/Hustler-Fundies-NU17-Monster-Python/dp/B009T6GABE) :-)

Comment: Do you see anything in the logfiles? You didn't mention which Linux you're using, but this is usually `/var/log/cron`. It's also possible the user running this has a mail with an error, so be sure to check that (if there's no alias in `/etc/aliases`, log in and run `mail`, or check `/var/mail/$user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a shell script to call the python script. THe anaconda on the box was causing the trouble

export PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python /opt/lampp/htdocs/scriptme.py >/opt/lampp/htdocs/scriptme.log 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Try to run script with another first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

If it's executes successfully the problem in python interpreter, because when you have several versions of Python installed, /usr/bin/env will ensure the interpreter used - is the **first one on your environment's $PATH**, which i guess **has no requests lib**.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines of code to your script and edit the crontab :

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())
```

Now check the log in crontab, you will get some path

```
e.g. "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"
```

*cd(change directory)* to the above path and *ls(list directory)* to check if package exists ; **if not** :

```
sudo pip3 install requests -t . # dot indicates current directory
```

or else if you have a *requirements.txt* file then you could try:

```
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt -t "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" 
#try this from the directory where  "requirements.txt" file exists
```

Now run your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you add `python` explicitly before the script name?
2. At the end of the crontab line, add `2>&1`, which redirects error messages to the log file as well. See this link for a detailed description [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)
3. There is also a possibility that your current user and `root` runs different versions of python.

Comment: Once i adde 2>&1 it gives an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/lampp/htdocs/kabeer/SPARK/k_collab_spark.2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests but if i execute the service manually it is successful . WHen i run it manually it works fine

Comment: It seems that sometimes `crontab` can have different environment, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths. If you manually set PATH or PYTHONPATH in crontab according to the link it should work.

Comment: WOuld invoking the python script from a pearl script be a good idea?

Comment: When you say you run it manually are you doing it as root or another user?

Comment: Can you add this to the beginning of the python code and see if it works? `import sys`, `sys.path.append('/path_to_your_lib')`