# mysql host server is not getting connected

Tags: java, mysql, unix, sh

I am writing an .sh file from where I am trying to access one .sql file where I have the query that needs to be run on scheduled basis.

Below is the line by which I try to make connection to the Database:

```
/home/mysql/mysql/bin/mysql --port=$PORT --host=$HOST --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWORD --database=$DB_NAME < ${SQL_SCRIPT_PATH}${SQL_SCRIPT_NAME} >> ${LOG_FILE_PATH}${LOG_FILE_NAME}
```

But, the problem is when the scheduler is executed, it gives the below error:

```
[example@mchpXXX TEST_sh]$ sh updateMonthlyUserData.sh
updateMonthlyUserData.sh: line 15: mysql: command not found
```

**Note:**
I tried to run this and got success if I run the sh file manually from putty and not through **scheduler**(*crontab*)

Kindly check and help.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab uses the default shell (sh) with minimal set of environment variables. most likely the PATH variable is not set properly.

I would set all the environment variables at the beginning of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/home/mysql/mysql/bin/:moreFolders
```

For further reading:
[How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work