# Not able to run shell script using crontab

Tags: php, centos, cron, centos7

I am able to run `sh /var/www/html/runcron.sh` manually

but when i put below lines in `crontab -e`. It is not getiing called.

```
*/2 * * * * /var/www/html/runcron.sh
```

Am I missing anything here?

I have written below code inside runcron.sh

```
php -f /var/www/html/cronscan.php
```

Comment: Does your script set a path? Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2388087/3124333

Comment: Need more info. Any errors in /var/log/cron? Who owns /var/www/html/cronscan.php?
Do you get notified when cron fails? If not, check /var/spool/mail/root

Comment: I cant see directories called  /var/log/cron and /var/spool/mail/root

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user running the cron has the proper permissions.And can access/ has ownership of the script. And just a quick reassurance, you want the job to run twice a minute?

Comment: I want to run cron every 2 minuts, By default root user will run the cron right? I logged in using root user and set the cron.

Comment: Right. Every 2 minutes. And I believe root is default. But if you had someone else trying to run the crons, they would not have permission. Also, if root did not create the script, it is possible that it has permissions for only that user.

Comment: Script was created by root user only.