# when I run some sh file using crone

Tags: linux, cron

when I run some sh file using crone. they did not recognized certain command line. 
 like Pyenv command.

```
*****  /home/ammt/apps/crawler/scripts/bat_start.sh
```

but it work fine when I type the whole thing after I log in to the Linux 
in what situation it does not recognize some command line?

if you need more setting information let me know

Comment: The environment can be different in a cron job versus your normal interactive shell...in this case, it sounds like your $path might be different.  You could edit the script to source your .bashrc, .bash_profile, .login etc. to give you the same environment you get in an interactive shell, or provide absolute pathnames to Pyenv or other tools that may not be on the default $path you get in the cron environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)