# Can I change default PATH variable of cronjob?

Tags: cron

I am porting from SuseLinux to CentOS

Default Path Variable of cronjob in Suse Linux was - `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`
All the Application Scripts worked fine in Suse Linux.

Now in CentOS, many binaries have been moved to `/usr/sbin` directories.

Now when these application scripts are run from cron job in CentOS they do not work because cron job default PATH in Centos is also `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. So these Cron scripts cannot access binaries present in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` directories.

Have to make `PATH` variable like `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin`
So that all my application scripts work.

I don't want to change Application Scripts and give the full path to all the binaries in these scripts. As it would produce many changes.

Setting `PATH` variable on top of Cron Script when the application installs and removing it when the application uninstalls, and even making changes during application upgrade also seems a lot of work.

I wanted to know the optimal or less work solution
It would be better if the change involves is in application side and I don't have to make changes in OS rpm.

Answer (score 0):

Centos is based on Redhat Enterprise Linux which makes use of vixie-cron. This allows you to change the path in the crontab file.

```
PATH=/usr:/usr/bin:/path/to/something/else
1 2 * * * command
```

More Information:

- [Centos 5.2 Manual](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s2-autotasks-cron-configuring.html)
- [Redhat Enterprise Linux Manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-autotasks#s1-autotasks-cron)
- [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)
- [Why is my crontab not working, and how can I troubleshoot it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it)