# docker: using screen to shut down minecraft server via cron job does not work

Tags: docker, cron, minecraft

I want to use docker for a minecraft server. The thing is that I need to shut it down properly to save the world every 24 hours. And to make things more complicated: the people on the server need be informed about this.

So my idea was using "screen" in conjunction with "cron":

```docker
################################
### We use a java base image ###
################################
FROM openjdk:8 AS build

MAINTAINER me <me@me.com>

#################
### Arguments ###
#################
ARG PAPERSPIGOT_CI_URL=https://papermc.io/ci/job/Paper-1.13/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/paperclip.jar

##########################
### Download paperclip ###
##########################
ADD ${PAPERSPIGOT_CI_URL} /opt/minecraft/server/paperclip.jar

############################################
### Run paperclip and obtain patched jar ###
############################################
RUN cd /opt/minecraft/server/ \
    && java -jar paperclip.jar; exit 0

RUN cd /opt/minecraft/server/ \
    && mv cache/patched*.jar paperspigot.jar

###########################
### Running environment ###
###########################
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:latest

###########################
### Install screen      ###
###########################
RUN apk --update add screen

#########################
### Working directory ###
#########################
WORKDIR /data

###########################################
### Obtain runable jar from build stage ###
###########################################
COPY --from=build /opt/minecraft/server/paperspigot.jar /opt/minecraft/server/paperspigot.jar

########################
### Obtain starth.sh ###
########################
ADD start.sh /opt/minecraft/server/start.sh

########################
### Obtain restart.sh ###
########################
ADD restart.sh /opt/minecraft/server/restart.sh

###########################################
### Configure and run cron              ###
###########################################
COPY crontab /etc/cron/crontab
# Init cron
RUN crontab /etc/cron/crontab

CMD ["crond", "-f"]

###############
### Volumes ###
###############
VOLUME "/data"

#############################
### Expose minecraft port ###
#############################
EXPOSE 25565

######################################
### Entrypoint is the start script ###
######################################
WORKDIR /data
ENTRYPOINT sh /opt/minecraft/server/start.sh
```

This is the start.sh script that seems to work:

```shell
#/bin/sh
cd /data
/usr/bin/screen -S minecraft /opt/jdk1.8.0_192/jre/bin/java -jar -Xms800M -Xmx800M -Dcom.mojang.eula.agree=true /opt/minecraft/server/paperspigot.jar
screen -ls
```

This is the restart script triggered via the crontab. I think it never gets started:

```shell
#!/bin/sh
# me - V1.1 - 18.05.2018
# Minecraft Server restart
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 30 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 23s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 7 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 6 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 5 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 4 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 3 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 2 seconds! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Server is restarting in 1 second! $(printf '\r')"
sleep 1s
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "say Closing server...$(printf '\r')"
screen -Rd minecraft -X stuff "stop $(printf '\r')"
sleep 15s
# echo "Updating to most recent paperclip version."
# wget -q https://papermc.io/ci/job/Paper-1.13/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/paperclip.jar -O /home/pi/minecraft/paperclip.jar
echo "Restarting now."
/opt/minecraft/server/start.sh
```

This is the crontab which should start restart.sh every 5 minutes. Does not happen:

```shell
*/5 * * * * /opt/minecraft/server/restart.sh
```

Maybe this is the wrong way to do this. Maybe there is a much better way to connect somehow to the screen session or to restart the server with a message somehow. But I did not find anything online. Any idea?

Comment: Is there any reason your script is handling the server announcements. Wouldn't an internal server code be better? Check if your pc time is nearing 12:00, and then if so, just warn players in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some testing and reading I came to the conclusion that using cron inside the container is the wrong why to do it.

I start and restart the docker container with docker. Since it is so fast I dont need to inform the ppl on the server. And the server gets properly stopped.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems here:

1. the `cron` daemon may not be installed in your Docker image, and
2. the cron job may be having problems locating executables in your Docker container

With regard to the first, I don't see anything installing `cron` in your Dockerfile. You probably want to check into the base image you're using - I know that I had to install it on an Ubuntu image I built a while back.

As for the second problem, the thing about running jobs in your crontab is that the environment is not what you expect it to be. Specifically, the `$PATH` variable, which the shell uses to find the commands you want to execute, is not set. As a result, many commands simply do not work because the shell doesn't know where to find them.

The "quick and dirty" way of fixing this is to ensure the `$PATH` variable is set in your crontab, by adding the following line:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/2008384) for more details.