# snowsql not found from cron tab

Tags: shell, cron, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute snowsql from an shell script which i have scheduled with cron job. But i am getting error like snowsql: command not found.

I went through many links where they are asking us to give full path of the snowflake. i tried with that also but no luck.
https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00007ZBOZnSAP/snowsql-through-shell-script. Below is my code snippet abc.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
 snowsql --config /home/basant.jain/snowsql_config.conf \
-D cust_name=mean \
-D feed_nm=lbl \
-o exit_on_error=true \
-o timing=false \
-o friendly=false \
-o output_format=csv \
-o header=false  \
-o variable_substitution=True \
-q 'select count(*) from table_name'
```

and my crontab looks like below:
`*/1 * * * * /home/basant.jain/abc.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron doesn't set `PATH` like your login shell does.

As you already wrote in your question you could specify the full path of `snowsql`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/snowsql --config /home/basant.jain/snowsql_config.conf \
...
```

Note: `/path/to/snowsql` is only an example. Of course you should find out the real path of `snowsql`, e.g. using `type snowsql`.

Or you can try to source `/etc/profile`. Maybe this will set up `PATH` for calling `snowsql`.

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile
snowsql --config /home/basant.jain/snowsql_config.conf \
...
```

see [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388087/10622916)

Comment: i checked but it is not helping

Comment: @BasantJain What exactly did you "check"?

Comment: I am specifying the full path like 
    #!/bin/bash
    /path/to/snowsql --config /home/basant.jain/snowsql_config.conf \

But stll it is saying /path/to/snowsql not found

Comment: @BasantJain I added a clarification. I don't know the correct path of `snowsql`.

Comment: i added below two lines in my corntab and it worked fine.
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

Thanks for the help