# CAT command in crontab

Tags: cron

I want to get the CPU percentage measured every minute and written to a file.
The command is as follow: 
Code: Select all

```
* * * * * cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | awk -v RS='' '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5)}' > /log/mainboard_cpu.log
```

If I run the code manually, I get the CPU written to the file but the cronjob doesn't do anything.
Is there another way to execute the command and write it to a file?
Thank you.

I am running the code on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1):

Crontab does not have PATH well defined, so you may need to use full path for command, like `/usr/bin/cat` (use `which` command to identify path).

Comment: Thank you, i used the which command to figure out the path and it gave me /bin/cat. I updated the crontab but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you any log in `/var/log/syslog` ?

Comment: Apr 25 15:15:01 TRM-RF01-134138 CRON[2469]: (root) CMD (/bin/cat <(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) <(sleep 1 && grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat) | /usr/bin/awk -v RS='' '{print ($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5)}' > /log/mainboard_cpu.log)
Apr 25 15:15:01 TRM-RF01-134138 CRON[2455]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

ps: i also updated awk with /usr/bin/awk but still nothing

Comment: personally I would have put the complete path to all commands (including grep and sleep), or define PATH at start.

Comment: Could you help me with that? I am willing to do that but i have no idea how to update this command (this is from internet but does exactly what i need)

Comment: This link can help you to define PATH for all crontab : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/3489104
If you want only for this command, simply add `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin;` before your command line.

Comment: Thank you for the help but it doesn't work yet. I added your line or the lines from the example and tried different combinaties wit cat, /bin/cat etc. but it doesn't create the file

Comment: Maybe it's not the only problem, your log in syslog indicate you do not have a mail command to transfert explicite logs. You can install mailx for that.

Comment: Now i did, but which email is used for the crontabs, the one i setup as root email?

This is the syslog output:

Apr 25 15:59:03 TRM-RF01-134138 cron[305]: sendmail: 550 5.7.1 Command rejected
Apr 25 15:59:03 TRM-RF01-134138 sSMTP[10595]: 550 5.7.1 Command rejected
Apr 25 15:59:03 TRM-RF01-134138 CRON[10560]: (root) MAIL (mailed 19 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)

Comment: mailx work with sendmail, you can configure MAILTO var in crontab, but mail can also be logged on system. May you have also more logs in `/var/cron/log`

Comment: Thanks but /var/cron/log is empty. i have setup the mail function but it doesn't send any mail. Is there another way to get this cronjob working?

Comment: You need log information to go further, may you have pending mail `sudo mailq` ?