# `/bin/sh: 1: python: not found` when run via cron in docker

Tags: python, docker, cron

I want to repeatedly call a script via cron in a docker container, but when I switch from one time execution to execution via cron the official python image suddenly can't seem to find python.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

COPY main.py /home/main.py

#A: works
CMD [ "python", "/home/main.py" ]

#B: doesn't work
#RUN  apt-get update && apt-get -y install -qq --force-yes cron
#COPY hello-cron /etc/cron.d/hello-cron
#CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

main.py

```
import time

for i in range(90000):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(5000)
```

hello-cron:

```
* * * * * root python /home/main.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2> /proc/1/fd/2
#
```

When I switch A for B in the Dockerfile the error message is: `/bin/sh: 1: python: not found`

Thank you all for he quick responses! Adding `PATH=/usr/local/bin` in the cron file solved my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)

Comment: `which python` to know the absolute path of python on the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cron doesn't set up the `PATH` environment variable the same as a normal login shell so `python` can't be found. It should work if you specify a complete path to the Python executable, e.g. replace `python` with `/usr/bin/python` (or whatever the path to your Python executable happens to be). Alternatively you can explicitly set the `PATH` environment variable in the Cron configuration file to include the directory where Python can be found.

Comment: Interestingly the complete path `PATH=/usr/local/bin/python` did not work for me, only the path to the directory `PATH=/usr/local/bin` did.

Comment: Oh, no, I meant using an absolute path to specify the python executable. Of course, changing the PATH environment variable works too, though as you sat you need to specify the directory. I'll reword my answer.

Comment: jesus crispy donut! this work for me! thx :)