# How can I run a python code with cron in a docker container?

Tags: docker, cron

I succeeded to run my python code in a docker container when using `CMD ["python3", "./mycode.py"]`.

Now, what I want is to run that python code every minute.

Dockerfile before(just run once):

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install cron -y
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN head -n -1 /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf > /etc/ssl/temp && \
       mv /etc/ssl/temp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "CipherString=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python3", "./mycode.py"]
```

Dockerfile after(run every minute with crontab):

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install cron -y
RUN pip3 install requests
RUN head -n -1 /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf > /etc/ssl/temp && \
       mv /etc/ssl/temp /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "CipherString=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf

RUN echo "* * * * * python /app/mycode.py" >> editcron && \
        crontab editcron

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

But after building and running a new docker image with `docker run -d --rm DockerImage`, it doesn't seem to work.(And also, there is no cron log file at /var/log directory)

When I went into the container with `docker exec -it DockerContainer /bin/bash`, I could confirm that `crontab -l` prints "* * * * * python /app/mycode.py", and that `python /app/mycode.py` runs properly.

What could be a problem here?

Comment: Small detail I just noticed: every crontab is expected to include a newline before EOF. Apparently, the crontab in the code fragment gets accepted allright, given the "crontab -l" output, but it is a detail that is easily overlooked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I often keep crontab configuration in a separate file, it keeps Dockerfile clean and understandable,

Here is Working example that you can try

```
FROM python:3.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron vim
WORKDIR /app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
COPY hello.py /app/hello.py
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

crontab config

```
#run python script every minutes
* * * * * python /app/hello.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

You can check complete working example in this Github Repo

[docker-python-cronjob](https://github.com/Adiii717/docker-python-cronjob)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the Github Repo! I copied this example, but I'm getting /bin/sh: 1: python: not found printed in the console...

Comment: Ok, the answer to the "python not found" issue is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61513681/bin-sh-1-python-not-found-when-run-via-cron-in-docker