# Bash script works when manually invoked but doesn't when invoked via cron

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi, ufw

I have two Bash scripts. `ufwBlock.sh` enables ufw and `ufwUnblock.sh` disables it

ufwBlock.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n `pidof firefox-esr` ]]
    then
        echo "Firefox is open, time to die (gracefully)...."
        kill -15 `pidof firefox-esr`
        logger -i Killed Firefox-esr
fi

ufw enable
logger -i enabled UFW 

#Test result
pingResult=`ping -c1 aws.com | grep received | awk '{print $4}'`

if [[ -n $pingResult  ]]
    then
        logger ufw enabled. Pinged aws.com but received $pingResult responses
    else    
        pingResult=0
        logger ufw enabled. Pinged aws.com and there was no response
fi

#Output rules <- This doesn't work!
rules=`ufw status`
logger $rules

if [[ $pingResult -gt 0 ]]
    then
        ufw default deny outgoing
        logger  ufw is enabled but ping got through, so added rule: ufw default to  deny outgoing
fi
```

and ufwUnblock.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
    ufw disable
    logger disabled the firewall
```

If I run `ufwBlock.sh` manually, it successfully (though slowly) detects and closes Firefox and enables the ufw firewall, blocking internet access for my video obsessed son until the `ufwUnblock.sh` script is run. I set up crontab (as root user)

```
# m     h       dom     mon     dow     command
0       20      *       *       *       /root/bin/ufwBlock.sh
30      7       *       *       *       /root/bin/ufwUnblock.sh
```

When cron triggers `ufwBlock.sh` it seems to work (see excerpt from `journalctl | grep ufw`, below) but I CAN STILL PING and running `ufw status` reports that ufw is disabled!

```
root@Pi7:/home/pi/# journalctl | grep ufw
Aug 02 20:00:01 Pi7 CRON[14554]: (root) CMD (/root/bin/ufwBlock.sh)
Aug 02 20:00:02 Pi7 root[14630]: ufw enabled. Pinged aws.com and received 1 responses
Aug 02 20:00:02 Pi7 root[14634]: ufw is enabled but ping got through, so added rule: ufw default to deny outgoing
root@Pi7:/home/pi# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

**If I leave it up to cron, nothing gets blocked! Is this a timing issue (script rushing ahead without previous action finishing)? or have I made a mistake somewhere?**

If it's relevant, this is all on a Pi4
`uname -a -> Linux Pi7 4.19.118-v7l+ #1311 SMP Mon Apr 27 14:26:42 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: XY problem? Can't you handle all this in your router?

Comment: To kill firefox takes time. Maybe do a `while [ -n \`pidof firefox-esr\``...

Comment: @Roadowl And even if it does take a while to kill firefox, what does that have to do with `ping`?

Comment: Try using the full path to the `ufw` command. A common problem in `cron` is that `$PATH` isn't set as you expect.

Comment: The logger text "ufw enabled. Pinged aws.com and received 1 responses" did not come from your script.

Comment: Read your script and tell me where it generated that message.

Comment: As @Barmar said, i think that problem is with you `$PATH` environment variable too. `ufw` doesn't run in `cron` shell environment. Export `$PATH` at the beginning of your script and try again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths is also another solution to define `$PATH` variable

Comment: @Roadowl presumably from `logger ufw enabled. Pinged aws.com but received $pingResult responses`

Comment: Although the word `but` seems to have changed to `and`. Maybe different versions of the script?

Comment: `and` to `but`  in `logger ufw enabled. Pinged aws.com _but_ received $pingResult responses` was a version change

Comment: @Roadowl. I originally tried doing this on my Linksys (openwrt) router but failed. Not sure why and worthy of a revisit. This looked like an expedient (easy & quick) alternative to keep my son from going square eyed and exercise free ;P

Comment: @barmar seems to have hit the nail on the head. Adding  the fully qualified path to ufw (`/usr/sbin/ufw`) has fixed this question.