# Shell Script to backup Git Repo w/ crontab

Tags: bash, git, shell, github, cron

My goal is to back up some markdown notes I keep in my `/Users/<me>/codes/notes` folder daily. I have a crontab job setup to run every minute to troubleshoot, but eventually I'd like this to be daily.

**crontab job**

```
* * * * * cd ~/codes/notes && ./backup_notes.sh
```

**backup_notes.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# create a timestamp alias for the commit message
timestamp() {
  date +"%Y-%m-%d @ %T"
}

# Go to my notes folder
cd /Users/<me>/codes/notes

# pull & push
if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
    git pull origin main
    git add .
    git commit -m "Update: $(timestamp)"
    git push origin main
fi
```

I believe the script by itself works because I can do:

```sh
❯ ./backup_notes.sh
```

And changes are pushed to the remote repository on github.

I also believe the crontab job is firing because if I add `echo "hello world" > ./log.txt` to the top of my `backup_notes.sh` I will get the expected `hello world` in `./log.txt`

I'm pretty stuck and would appreciate it if anyone has any advice on how I can troubleshoot.

Things I've tried:

- Replace `git` with `/usr/local/bin/git`
- Remove the conditional
- Double checked `chmod 744 ~/codes/notes/backup_notes.sh`
- Added `* * * * * cd ~/codes/notes && echo "hello world" > ./log.txt` to verify that the crontab was working, and this will put `hello world` into `log.txt`.

I've also added some `echos`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# create a timestamp alias for the commit message
timestamp() {
  date +"%Y-%m-%d @ %T"
}

# Go to my notes 
cd /Users/jesse.spevack/codes/notes

echo "job started: $(timestamp)" > log.txt

# pull & push
if [[ `git status --porcelain` ]]; then
  echo "Running Git commands: $(timestamp)" >> log.txt
  git pull origin main
  git add .
  git commit -m "Update: $(timestamp)"
  git push origin main
  echo "Finished running Git commands: $(timestamp)" >> log.txt
fi

echo "job done: $(timestamp)" >> log.txt
```

Which adds the following to my `log.txt`:

```
job started: 2021-03-14 @ 09:12:00
Running Git commands: 2021-03-14 @ 09:12:00
Finished running Git commands: 2021-03-14 @ 09:12:01
job done: 2021-03-14 @ 09:12:01
```

However, there is no affect on the remote repository on github.

Comment: BTW double bracket notation `[[` is a bashism, so you should change your shebang to bash (though I assume this isn't the root cause since you mentioned it also failed without the conditional).

Comment: For debugging, try leaving unstaged changes in your repo, then check the repo status after the cronjob fires to see whether those changes are still unstaged, staged, committed, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your script under a reduced environment, like

```
 env -i HOME=$HOME ./backup_notes.sh
```

You might find that the script should set `PATH` or some other variable not found in a cron environment. To inspect the (quite limited) cron environment, place `set` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: I noticed I had `GITHUB_API_TOKEN` set in my shell, but the cron job did not. I've added that to the cron job. Any other env things you think I should look at?

Comment: @JesseSpevack Most commonly PATH must be set to find all utilities. You'll know if you have "command not found: foo" errors.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:

A script I wrote was not able to push contents of a git repo to github

### Cause:

1. The script did not have the right path variables
2. The repo was not setup with an SSH remote

### Solution:

1. Set up path and shell for crontab - [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)
2. Set up SSH for the repo in question - `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git` see: https://gist.github.com/developius/c81f021eb5c5916013dc

Helpful debugging tips:

1. Add a log.txt file
2. Use `echo "Some text" > log.txt` liberallyh
3. Capture errors and command outputs by `<my command> 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt` for exampel `git pull origin main 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt`