# pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found when using Crontab to execute

Tags: python, cron, latex, pdflatex, pylatex

I am trying to run this line of code to generate a report using pylatex:

```
doc.generate_pdf(report_name, clean_tex=True)
```

This works well to generate a pdf file without any error when I use Spyder and Jupyter Notebook to execute the program, but when I try to use Crontab to automate my task by executing the exact same py file every day,

```
0 6 * * * cd /Users/me/my_folder && /anaconda3/bin/python3 MyProgram.py
```

the following error occurs via terminal mail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "MyProgram.py", line 255
doc.generate_pdf(report_name, clean_tex=True)
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pylatex/document.py", line 299, in generate_pdf
'No LaTex compiler was found\n'
pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found
Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.
```

I have spent hours searching for solutions online but still cannot fix the bug. So I would like to get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the location of your compiler? Cron uses different PATH, e.g. doesn't have /usr/bin in there. You can either pass the full location to the call ("Either specify a LaTex compiler") or change the location of your compiler to e.g. /bin (which is in cron's PATH) or add a local link... or change what PATH cron uses - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/11516012

Comment: The problem has been solved by passing the full location to the call. Thanks a lot.    
    doc.generate_pdf(report_name, clean_tex=True, compiler="/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex")