# Can not running a Go app (using os library) with cron job

Tags: go, cron

I had a problem when I tried run a Go app with cron job. It's seem that every func of os library can not execute in cron job. Here is my code. I've searched for a lot of time but haven't got any solotion yet.

**Here is my code.**

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "os"
   "os/exec"
)

func main() {
   out, err := exec.Command("ls").Output()
   file, _ := os.Create("test.txt")
   _, err1 := file.Write([]byte(string(out) + "\n"))
   if err == nil && err1 == nil {
       fmt.Println("test")
   }
   fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

**Here is my cron job**

```
* * * * * go run /root/code/main.go
```

Please help me fix this problem or any recommend to run a go app with cron job.

Comment: Probably go binary isn't in your `PATH`. You can check error messages in cronjob by being logged on the machine while the cronjob is active. you will get a notification of a new e-mail message after the cronjob runs, it will have the error.

Comment: @Niloct Thanks for your sharing, the strange thing is I run my piece of code complete normal manually but in cron job, it can be executed. There is no error in cronjob log. 
https://i.imgur.com/ps4Ji76.png

Comment: Do not use go run for such stuff.

Comment: "the strange thing is" - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2388087/11810946) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, cron jobs are run with the `root` user, and probably there is no `go` binary in your root user's path.
To check this, you can run.

```
# crontab -e
* * * * * whoami >> /tmp/debug.txt && where go && echo OK >> /tmp/debug.txt || echo ERROR >> /tmp/debug.txt
```

Which will show you user info and "Can I find go binary" information.

You can change the user who [runs the cronjob](https://serverfault.com/questions/352835/crontab-running-as-a-specific-user)

### Better Way

As others said, it's not a good idea to run Go code with `go run`. Each time compiler needs to compile the code and run it.

If you run `go build` and run the produced executable, it'll simplify your workflow. Also, by default, go binaries are single binaries that contain all dependencies, which simplifies lots of things. You can just `./executable-name` anywhere

Comment: Thanks sir, that helped a lot. I fixed my problem by adding go binary path at the begin of crontab file.