# using wget in a cron job to download files onto my server

Tags: cron, wget

I use a service to generate sitemaps and i'm trying to automate the retrieval process.

I have been using wget to fetch the data and add it to my server

here is my wget statement:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --quiet \
  --output-document sitemap.xml \
  --method POST \
  --timeout=0 \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --body-data 'method=download_sitemap&api_key=[SECRET_KEY]&site_id=[SECRET_ID]&sitemap_id=sitemap.xml' \
   'https://pro-sitemaps.com/api/'
```

^this code works great for me no issues.

I `cronjob -e` and added the code to my cron folder using nano which looks like this

```
25 0 * * * "/etc/letsencrypt"/acme.sh --cron --home "/etc/letsencrypt" > /dev/null
07 18 * * * wget --no-check-certificate --quiet \  --output-document "/FILE/PATH/sitemap.xml" \  --method POST \  --timeout=0 \  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \ --body-data 'method=download_sitemap&api_key=[SECRET_KEY]&site_id=[SECRET]&sitemap_id=sitemap.xml' \ 'https://pro-sitemaps.com/api/'
```

My problem is that my code is not running in the cron folder. I have set up the time, so my server time matches my local time. I have tried running the wget statement all on one line and removing any extra spacing in the code block. I tried shorthanding the commands (-T instead of --timeout) & I have tried adding a space at the end of each cron job. I am a bit stumped. Its probably something really simple that I missed in the documentation. Does anybody have any suggestions or notice anything off with what i'm doing in my cron folder?

I have observed these two q's which is where I have gotten the ideas so far troubleshooting: [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)
& this q: [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running)

Again, I have no issues when I run the wget statement in my terminal. It pulls everything just as expected. My issues is just when I put the wget command in my cron folder the command wont run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` denotes line continuation, you should not use it if you have all in one line command, for example

```
wget --continue \
  https://www.example.com
```

after conversion to one line is

```
wget --continue https://www.example.com
```

Regarding `cron` if you have working command you might create file with it and use it through `bash` e.g. you might create `fetcher.sh` with content as follows

```
wget -P /path/to/catalog https://www.example.com
```

inside `/path/to/catalog` and then add

```
58 23 * * * bash /path/to/catalog/fetcher.sh
```

where `/path/to/catalog` is path to existing catalog, then it would download example domain into `/path/to/catalog` each 2 minutes to midnight.

Comment: Putting the wget functions into a bash file worked great for me. Thank you for your detailed reply!